# Ajax не срабатывает событие success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Есть такой вот код:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/include/oneclick_addcoupon.php", // куда отправляем
        type: "post", // метод передачи
        dataType: "json", // тип передачи данных
        data: {
            "coupon": coupon
        },
// после получения ответа сервера
        success: function(data){
            console.log(222);
            $('.answer').html('');
            $('.answer').html(data.result); // выводим ответ сервера
        }
    });
```

А вот содержимое **oneclick_addcoupon.php**

```
// Какие-то там действия, не имеющие отношения к делу
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

echo json_encode(array(
    'result' => $msg_box
));
```

Событие success никак не хочет отрабатывать

Заголовки:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
```

Response

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2019 08:14:20 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
P3P: policyref="/bitrix/p3p.xml", CP="NON DSP COR CUR ADM DEV PSA PSD OUR UNR BUS UNI COM NAV INT DEM STA"
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.14.2
Set-Cookie: BITRIX_SM_ABTEST_s1=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: BITRIX_SM_ABTEST_s1=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: BITRIX_SM_ABTEST_s1=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-CMS: Bitrix Site Manager (cd29cd82eba63dd71f175ab3e29c2b1f)
```

Comment: Раз оно не отрабатывает, значит отрабатывает errors событие! Подключите и dump ошибки сделайте, возможно что-то падает в серверном файле

Comment: добавьте error: function(xhr)... и можно будет о чём-то говорить

Comment: тело ответа уж приведите заодно. там точно валидный json у вас?

Comment: Разобрался. Одни из подключаемых файлов в php скрипте возвращал кусок html, вместо JSON

Comment: "кусок html" это сгенерированная браузером страница с сообщением об ответе сервера с кодом 500. Но то такое))

Comment: @Kirill  нет. Кусок html - это кусок вполне валидного html.

Comment: Который там затесался, потому что какая-то псина переписала файлы ядра, которые никогда не должны генерить html, а только должны подключать классы приложения